# Application Insight stopped sending data to portal

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-cloud-services, azure-application-insights

We already use Application Insight for diagnostics our cloud service project.

Today I added AppInsight Telemetry to project from Visual studio.
It added some lines to web config and nuget packages.
But after deployed it stopped sending data to Visual Studio Portal. No telemetry data and diagnostic data.
Now I rollback changes.

How can I add AppInsight Telemetry to out project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2013 open Tools, Extensions and Updates,

Select `Installed` on the left and look for `Application Insight Tools for Visual Studio` and check its version. If it is version 2, uninstall it. This one sends the telemetry data to Azure instead of VS Online (portal that you mentioned above).

Now select `Online` and search for `Application Insight Tools for Visual Studio`, you will see 1.3.2 version. Install it, restart the Visual Studio and `Add Application Insights Telemetry to the project...`, it will show you VS Online account that it will use and the Application Insight component under  which data will be captured. Run the app and after few minutes data will appear in the VS Online portal.

You can add Application Insight in Visual Studio 2012 as well. However, it is a manual process and involves below steps:

- Create Application Insight application in VS Online portal
- Add Nuget package to the project in VS
- Finally, add few lines of code in `Global.asax.cs`